# Is it possible to turn "-Wwrite-strings" into an error?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I've tested this on GCC 4.8.3, 4.9.2 and trunk 20141210. When using `-Werror=write-strings`, it correctly enables the warning, but doesn't turn it into an error. The command line I'm using is:

```
g++ -std=c99 -x c -Werror=write-strings -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp
warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type

     char *s = "test";
```

However, it turns it into an error in C++ mode:

```
g++ -Werror=write-strings -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
main.cpp:8:15: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' 
  [-Werror=write-strings]

     char *s = "test";
```

Is there something I'm missing or is this just a missing feature?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the deleted answer, but bear with me…it was actually correct (at least, under my testing).  I think what you've found is interesting, and close to being a bug.

As far as my testing goes (GCC 4.9.1 built on Mac OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks, running on Mac OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite), it appears that the `-Werror=write-strings` does not make the warning into an error (which I regard as being probably a bug, though you may find that the GCC team has a different view on it).  It only becomes an error when `-Werror` is in effect.

Here's what I ran:

```
$ cat x.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *test = "data";
    printf("%s\n", test);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wwrite-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Werror=write-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Werror -Wwrite-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror]
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror=write-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror]
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Werror=write-strings
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:5:18: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror]
     char *test = "data";
                  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

For your convenience, and for easier viewing, these are the GCC commands I ran:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wwrite-strings
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Werror=write-strings
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Werror -Wwrite-strings
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror=write-strings
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -c x.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Werror=write-strings
```

If you can't run with `-Werror` normally, then you're probably going to have to do trial builds with `-Werror -Wwrite-strings` which will fail because of other problems, but this will also identify the writable strings problems, which you can fix and check.  Then, when you're OK on the `-Wwrite-strings` errors, you can go back to not including `-Werror` in the compilation (keeping `-Wwrite-strings` or even `-Werror=write-strings` in the command line so that if you make a mistake and/or the putative compiler bug is fixed, then you can have it all working the way you really wanted).

Comment: At the moment, gcc's bugzilla's account creation is closed. Can you submit a bug report for me? (If you think it's necessary.)

Comment: Can you do a search on their bugzilla and see whether there is any evidence of this having been reported before.  Basically, could you look for `-Wwrite-strings` or `-Werror=write-strings` and see what bugs have been reported that might be related to this putative bug.  If you can't find anything relevant, then I'll dig out my credentials and create the bug; the source is not bad (but the preprocessed source they request will be big; I need to create a repro that doesn't require even `<stdio.h>`; replace that line with `extern void function(const char *str);` and call it instead of `printf()`.

Comment: Not really, all I found is [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35648), where one of the commenters says that `-Werror=write-strings` should do the trick. Plus a bunch of search results that show people using it.

Comment: GCC bug [61579](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61579) is interesting — and may in part explain the behaviour we're seeing.  This could be an addendum to that bug.  At the least, we should cross-reference 61579 when we create a bug.  There's also the comment about the history of '-Wwrite-strings' which is revealing — it was what I was worried about.

Comment: In trunk, I can turn it into an error with `-Werror=write-strings -Werror=discarded-qualifiers`. `-Werror=discarded-qualifiers` by itself doesn't do anything (at least for `char *s = "test"`), so I *think* that they started working on it.